# FT311D Accessory Launch Application from Google Play

Tags: format, usb, google-play, accessory

I am using the FT311D Device from FTDI on my USB accessory - http://www.ftdichip.com/Android.htm

This device will place the Android Phone into a Slave mode and my USB Accessory will be the master.

Here is what I would like to do:

1. Insert the Accessory into the MicroUSB Port of the Android Phone.
2. Send a "string" from my device to go directly to Google Play and download the specific App for my accessory.
3. After Download of the App from Google Play, I want to launch the App.

Does the Open Accessory Format Support this feature?

Answer (score 0):

yes
pls use google play to search FT311D/Passiontech, there is an apk , it is for FT311D UART
by the way, GPIO version , will be posted soon.